# My non-EU husband working in Ireland

Tags: eu-citizens, immigration, ireland

I am a EU citizen. Recently got married to non-EU citizen. We have a marriage certificate done in Mexico where we got married.

Now, I have a job in EU (Ireland). How can my non-EU husband accompany me Ireland and work? What steps we should take?  What documents are needed to proceed so my non-EU husband work and live in EU with me?

Comment: You are an EU citizen but not an Irish one, is that right? (it does matter)

Comment: Note that the only issue is obtaining a residence permit as EU citizen family member in Ireland (apparently called a “residence card” in this case). He would then be automatically entitled to work and does *not* need to specifically obtain a work visa following whatever rules Ireland might have in place for those.

Answer (score 8):

1. Make sure your marriage is legal in the country you were married
2. Get a copy of your marriage certificate
3. Move to Ireland and have your spouse apply for a Residence Card

### Make sure your marriage is legal

While Ireland will recognize a marriage conducted overseas, it needs to be a legally valid marriage in the country where it is conducted.

From [Ireland Citizens Information Website](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/birth_family_relationships/getting_married/getting_married_abroad.html):

> If you or your partner are an Irish citizen(s) and are thinking of getting married outside of Ireland, you should realise that the legal validity of your marriage is governed, in part, by the laws of the country in which you marry. In most, if not all cases, the legal formalities abroad are very different to those in Ireland. For example, a church marriage abroad is usually a purely religious ceremony with no legal effect. Because it is not recognised in law in the country in which it takes place, it cannot be regarded as a legal marriage in Ireland. This is the case even though a marriage in the same church or denomination in Ireland can be legally binding.

### Get a copy of your marriage certificate

To prove that you are married, you need to bring the marriage certificate from that country as proof (translated if it is in a foreign language).

From [Ireland Citizens Information Website](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/birth_family_relationships/getting_married/getting_married_abroad.html):

> Your foreign marriage certificate will usually be accepted for official purposes in Ireland where you need to show evidence that you are married. If the certificate is in a foreign language, you must provide an official translation or a translation from a recognised translation agency.

### Apply for a Residence Card

Your spouse will need to apply for a residence card [within 3 months](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/worker-pensioner/non-eu-family-members/spouses-children-parents_en.htm) of arriving in Ireland.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stamp_4#EU_Directive_2004.2F38.2FEC.23Stamp_4):

> Family members of EEA nationals exercising Treaty rights in Ireland in accordance with EU Directive 2004/38/EC, who are not themselves EEA nationals, are required to apply for a "Residence Card of a family member of a Union citizen", as described in Article 10 of the Directive. In Ireland, applications for the Residence Card, are made on form [EU1](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Form%20EU1.pdf/Files/Form%20EU1.pdf) and sent to the EU Treaty Rights Section of the Department of Justice ... Once processed, a letter is sent to the applicant, instructing him or her to visit their local Garda National Immigration Bureau (GNIB), in order to receive their Residence Card.

Note that this application process can take up to 6 months, and certain original documents are required to be submitted (no photocopies accepted) which will limit your ability to travel, so plan accordingly:

**Evidence of identity:**

- Spouse's passport
- Your passport or National Identity Card

**Evidence of relationship of applicant to EU citizen:**

- Civil Marriage Certificate (for Spouse)
- Partnership Certificate (for Civil Partner)

**Evidence of residence in the State:**

- Utility bills in the names of both the applicant and the EU citizen
- If Renting:

  - Letter from landlord/agency, rental contract or tenancy agreement
  - Letters of Registration of Tenancy from the Private Residential Tenancies Board
- If Home-owning:

  - Letter from mortgage provider, local authority or County Council
  - Copy of title or deeds as applicable

**Evidence of current activity of EU citizen in the State:**

One of the following (with supporting documents, see [form EU1 Section 4](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Form%20EU1.pdf/Files/Form%20EU1.pdf) for details):

- Proof of employment
- Proof of self-employment
- Proof of study
- Proof of involuntary unemployment
- Proof of financial self-sufficiency

Answer (score 0):

An update on jmac's excellent answer. The [INIS now recommends that you submit photocopies of your documents](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/EUTreatyRightsFAQs#Q4) as they will not be returned until the process is complete, which can take 6 months or more.